# Returning data from if statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, return

I'm handling data in an if statement, and would like to keep that data as an not-locale variable, so I can call on it outside of the statement. Here's the actual code. Beware; it's pretty much just the outcast of an idea, but I'll welcome any and all ideas or better solutions (provided the suggestions aren't too advanced for my current level)...

The code creates and multidimensional char array (2 dimensions), and fills it. When trying to call on it afterwards, the programs crashes as a result of reaching a unassigned array value.

```
       do
       {
        destRow = ( rand() % ROWS ) + 1; // assigning random placement for destroyer ship
        destCol = ( rand() % COLLUMS ) + 1;
        destDir = ( rand() % 2 ) + 1;

        if ( destDir == 1 ) { //Destroyer: 1 = right
            if ( destCol + 1 > COLLUMS ) {
                continue;
            } else {
                char enemyDestroyer[DESTROYER_SIZE][2] = { { board[destCol][0] , board[0][destRow] }, { board[destCol + 1][0] , board[0][destRow] } };
            }

        } else if ( destDir == 2 ) { //Destroyer: 2 = down
            if ( destRow + 1 > ROWS ) {
                continue;
            } else {
                char enemyDestroyer[DESTROYER_SIZE][2] = { { board[destCol][0] , board[0][destRow] }, { board[destCol][0] , board[0][destRow + 1] } };
            }
        }
        destSucces = true;
    } while (!destSucces);
```

Here it checks the player input (gathered at some other point) with the data, set above, which hasn't actually been set to anything because the assignment happend in an if-statement

```
if ( ( input[0] == enemyDestroyer[0][0] && input[1] == enemyDestroyer[0][1] ) || (input[0] == enemyDestroyer[1][0] && input[1] == enemyDestroyer[1][1] ) ) {
    cout << "Hit!" << endl;
    board[posY][posX] = '!';
    getchar();

    //setting display damage
    if ( input[1] == enemyDestroyer[0][1] ) {
        enmDesDisp[0] = '!';
    } else if ( input[1] == enemyDestroyer[1][1] ) {
        enmDesDisp[1] = '!';
    }
} else {
    cout << endl << "Splash!" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the language you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear which array you are refering to. The only array you're interacting with in the code is `enemyDestroyer`, which is immediately released from memory after the assignment.

Perhaps you could expand you example so we can get a better understanding of what it is you're trying to do?

**Update**

To prevent `enemyDestroyer` from being instantly released youd have to move it to the appropriate scope. That would mean declaring it in the same scope it's going to be used.

I suggest reading up on scopes and perhaps switching to an object oriented design.

Comment: Well... If you add "cout << enemyDestroyer[0][0];" after the loop, that would pretty much be it .__.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want it to be released from memory, I want it, and the values assigned to it in the if statement, to be usable throughout the rest of the program.